# Retrieving an Array from the servlet to jsp

Tags: jsp, servlets

I have a jsp page where user makes a search of a car by a reg. number.

I've got a servlet that makes this search, retrieves results and passes it back to the same jsp page with the help of Java Expression Language. As it turned out i'm not allowed to use EL, so I'm looking for a way of running a specific function of servlet that would return an aray from the jsp page. So I could use this array on my jsp. Any ideas how i can use my servlet methods of an array type from the jsp?

**Answered***
I can simply put needed array into the request attribute on the server page and than use request.getAttribute("name_of_the_array"); from the jsp page.

Comment: Your question is not clear. The servlet doesn't use the EL (the EL is only usable by the JSP). It puts the array in a request attribute. The JSP can then get this array from the request attribute. Whether the JSP uses EL or not, the way to set the array in a request attribute stays identical. Post the relevant code from the servlet and the JSP, and telle us what you'd like to change in this code.

Comment: @JB Nizet Which command should I use to get a variable from the request attribute on the jsp page?

Comment: Why exactly are you not allowed to use EL? It has since 10 years ago been the recommended approach for accessing data in JSPs. I can't imagine that you're currently working on a completely outdated server environment. Or is it homework and is it actually your tutor who is by itself completely outdated? Oh, please note that you shouldn't confuse request parameters with request attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Use the EL. If you can't, ask the person forbidding it why he doesn't want you to use the EL. This is the right thing to do. If it's because the container is really old and can't be changed, then use

```
<% Foo[] array = (Foo[]) request.getAttribute("theNameOfTheRequestAttribute") %>
```

Comment: there is a problem when my jsp is loaded for the first time without setted request attribute there is an error (some kind of Jusper exeption) when retrieving an attribute. how to fix it?

Comment: Test if the dereferenced variable is null before dereferencing it.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, and you're trying to pass an array from the servlet to the jsp. You could try something like:

```
int[] cars=//your code
request.setAttribute ("cars", cars);
```

and then pass on your request to the jsp.

Comment: there is a problem when my jsp is loaded for the first time without setted request attribute there is an error (some kind of Jusper exeption) when retrieving an attribute. how to fix it?

Comment: Just call the URL of the servlet instead of the JSP? See also http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info

Answer (score 0):

use scriptlets for EL
that is

```
<% %>
```

for receiving a variable

```
<% String var=request.getParameter("var_at_java");) %>
```

For receiving an array

```
String[] var_array=request.getParameterValues("var_array_at_java");
```